# nuget pack doesn't include project dependencies

Tags: nuget

Scenario:

- Project B references Project A.
- Project B and A both have .nuspec files and packages.config files
- Command issued: `for /R %%f in (Company.*.csproj) do nuget pack "%%~ff" -Properties Configuration=Release -BasePath "%%~dpf" -IncludeReferencedProjects`

All project packages get created successfully, but the nuget package for project B does not include project A as a nuget package dependency. I thought this was the purpose of IncludeReferencedProjects. What am I missing?

Comment: This appears to be a bug that only manifests when nuget pack is called from a different directory than the one the .csproj file resides in. Even when -BasePath is specified, the reference is not picked up, but if I run nuget pack in the project directory, all works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Can you search https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced to see if there are already an issue for it? If not, would you please open a new issue there, thanks!